# restriction on number of branch points of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, covering-spaces

The image of the function $z^n$ is an $n$-fold covering of the Riemann sphere with two branch points at 0 and $\infty$.

Is there a holomorphic function that covers the Riemann sphere with exactly one branch point?

I guess more generally, I'm asking if there is some restriction on the number of branch points a holomorphic function could have.

I have no knowledge of algebraic topology and was wondering if this question had an answer within complex analysis.

Comment: You certainly mean "Is there a holomorphic $n$-fold coverning of  the Riemann sphere with exactly one branch point for $n > 1$?"